# Font smoothing color wrong

Tags: css, macos, fonts, colors, chromium

I am creating a theme for GitHub's new editor Atom, which uses Chromium behind the scenes. Therefore this issue also applies to chrome (on OS X).

I noticed that my text colors are darker then they are supposed to be.

After wrestling with the styles being applied I found that:

1. This issue does not happen on retina displays (on my retina macbook pro I don't see a color difference but I can clearly see the difference on my thunderbolt display)
2. With `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased` I see the color difference (this is the default for OS X)
3. With `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` the color difference is gone but the font renders too thin

I created a fiddle to demonstrate the color difference here: http://jsfiddle.net/KFYuG/

I think the "thickness" of the font is perfect when `webkit-font-smoothing` is set to `subpixel-antialiased` but I need to prevent the color from darkening on non-retina displays.

How would I correct the color so it renders correctly on non-retina displays?

Comment: I can't see a color difference on Google Chrome 34 on Mac OS X 10.9. Everything works like it's supposed to do.

Comment: @KittMedia Really? I myself am running OS X 10.9.3 w/ Chrome 34 on a Thunderbolt display. What type of monitor are using? Retina? Thunderbolt?

Comment: Yeah, really. ;) I'm using a MacBook Air 2011, thus without Retina.

Comment: @KittMedia interesting... maybe its just my thunderbolt display. Could you post a screenshot of what you see?